# Unable to mock Auto Mapper in .Net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, mocking, nunit, automapper

net core 3.1 and I am using auto mapper. I am writing unit test cases and I have below piece of code

```
var coOrdinateReferenceSystemNames = await _coordinateReferenceSystemRepository.GetAsync(x => x.CoordinateReferenceSystemName.Contains(request.searchName)).ConfigureAwait(false);

IEnumerable<CoordinateReferenceSystemModel> CoordinateReferenceSystemList = _mapper.Map<IEnumerable<CoordinateReferenceSystemModel>>(coOrdinateReferenceSystemNames);
```

Below is my unit test case.

```
 Func<IEnumerable<CoordinateReferenceSystem>> func = () => { return new List<CoordinateReferenceSystem>() { coordinateReferenceSystemModel }; };

 this.mockMapper.Setup(x => x.Map<IEnumerable<CoordinateReferenceSystem>>(It.IsAny<IEnumerable<CoordinateReferenceSystemModel>>())).Returns(func);
```

Which throws below error

```
One or more errors occurred. (IMapperBase.Map>([CoordinateReferenceSystem]) invocation failed with mock behavior Strict. All invocations on the mock must have a corresponding setup.)
```

Can someone help me to understand this error and Which part I am doing wrong here. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Hi I have added mock mapper as below and started working fine.

```
 private CoordinateReferenceSystemAr CreateCoordinateReferenceSystemAr()
        {
            var mockMapper = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            {
                cfg.AddProfile(new MappingProfile());
            });
            var mapper = mockMapper.CreateMapper();

            return new CoordinateReferenceSystemAr(this.mockApiRequestHandler.Object,this.mockUnitOfWork.Object, mapper);
        }
```